# Comments not showing up in admin page

Tags: comments, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-comments

Our user comments stopped showing up at developers.facebook.com/tools/comments all of a sudden.  I don't believe we changed anything at the site that would have caused it.  We have the following within the head tag in every page that has FB comments (with our appid properly inserted).

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{YOUR_APPLICATION_ID}"/>
```

Any ideas on what to look for to try to fix this?

Comment: can you add all the code you are using to render the comments box please.

Comment: Looks like it had to do with an OG tag that was sitting on one of the pages.  So we have it resolved.  Thanks Shawn for offering to look at the code.